# flutter pub get keeps running endlessly

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-dependencies

Flutter pub get just keeps running endlessly and refusing to launch the app. It seems pub.dartlang.org site is down. Am I the only one experiencing this or is there something I'm doing wrong? Help please.

Tried launching flutter app using vs code and the message Running "flutter pub get"... just shows unending and the app doesn't launch.